# Modifying a Query fetched from DB (i.e., considering Clauses) When DROPDOWN item is selected

Tags: dropdown

Query:

```
"SELECT COUNT(ID)AS 'COUNT(ID) from tbl_Leads WHERE UserID={Current User}"
```

Modification:

```
if (Query.IndexOf("WHERE") > 0) {                        
    if (Query.Contains("UserID = {CurrentUser}")) {
        Query = Query.Replace("UserID = {CurrentUser}", "UserID IN (" + UserIDs + ")");
        if (dropdownValue != 0) {
            Query += "";
            Query+= "AND FKiLeadClassID="+dropdownValue;
        }
    }
    if (Query.Contains("OrganizationID = {CurrentUser}")) {
        Query = Query.Replace("OrganizationID = {CurrentUser}", "OrganizationID=" + OrganizationID);
        if (dropdownValue != 0) {
            Query += "";
            Query += "AND FKiLeadClassID=";
            Query += dropdownValue;
        }
    }                       
}     
else if(Query.IndexOf("WHERE") == 0) {
    if (dropdownValue != 0) {
        Query += " Where";
        Query += " FKiLeadClassID=";
        Query += dropdownValue;
    }
}
```

NEED: PLEASE CONSIDER "GROUPBY" and "ORDERBY" clauses as well.

I WANT :

```
"SELECT COUNT(ID)AS 'COUNT(ID) from tbl_Leads WHERE UserID IN (234) AND FKiLeadClassID=43"
```

(if no groupby or orderby)

OR

I WANT :

```
"SELECT COUNT(ID)AS 'COUNT(ID) from tbl_Leads WHERE UserID IN (234) AND FKiLeadClassID=43"  GROUPBY(something) ORDERBY(something).
```

Comment: ok i wont shout but my TeamLead is .... please answer...

Comment: Giving it a look. By the way, could you please re-indent the code you posted?

Comment: Actually I don't understand what you want to do. I mean, you wrote these "I WANT" lines, but I don't really get what you want your queries to do...

Comment: i just want to add (WHERE ClassType=dropdwonValue) in the query if NO WHERE  CLAUSE exists.....

Comment: If exists the ADD ClassType=dropdwonValue

Comment: if GROUPBY or ORDERBY exists then do nothing....

Comment: But what's the problem? Why can't you just do it? Where  does it not work?

Comment: Do Nothing means.....  split the Query till you find GROUPBY and add where condition.......then again add GROUPBY substring to the query

Comment: i'm unable to SPlit the Query and add my where condition then add groupby/orderby

Comment: How about parsing the query until you find `"GROUP BY"` or `"ORDER BY`", and just add the condition where you found it?

Comment: ok...please provide code

Comment: Sorry no time to code now, just wanted to clarify your need.

Comment: How can i split the query in two halves and get the second half.

Comment: Split the QUERY till "GROUPBY" is found and save this second half from (GROUPBY) and save it in one variable.

Add WHERE condition to first half. Then add the GROUPBY part to it.